# Binary Classifier Model trained with batch generated using ImageDataGenerator not giving same result without ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have trained my binary classification model by feeding data to the fit_generator using ImageDataGenerator.
I haven't used any augumentation options, i have used ImageDataGenerator just to resize the image to 224x224x3.
Below is my training code.

```
def get_batches(directory, target_size=target_size, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False):
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
    return datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=directory,
                                          target_size=target_size,
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          class_mode='categorical',
                                          shuffle=shuffle)


batches = get_batches(train_dataset, shuffle=True)
valid_batches = get_batches(validation_dataset, shuffle=True)

model.fit_generator(batches, steps_per_epoch=batches.samples//batch_size, nb_epoch=150,
                    validation_data=valid_batches,
                    callbacks= [early_stop, checkpoint, tensorboard, time_callback, TerminateOnNaN()],
                    validation_steps=valid_batches.samples//batch_size)
```

I have got decent training result and i trained evaluating with a test set.

```
batches = get_batches(evaluation_dataset, shuffle=True)

pred_acc = top_model.predict_generator(batches, steps=batches.samples//batch_size)
```

I am getting decent evaluation accuracy as expected.

I tried the same operation with predict function instead of predict_generator and i resized the image on my own instead of ImageDataGenerator.

```
image = cv2.imread ("xyz.bmp")
image_resized = cv2.resize(image, (224,224))

pred_img = np.expand_dims(image_resized, axis=0)

prediction = top_model.predict(pred_img)
```

I am not getting the same model output when i used predict for the same images fed to predict_generator using ImageDataGenerator.

I can't use ImageDataGenerator for my real time use.

What could be the issue?

Any pointers.

I have seen some discussions similar to this issue https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3477#issuecomment-360022086, but for my case i have verified for both positive and negative cases and result is always same irrespective of input image. Looks like ImageDataGenerator is doing some modifiction in data which i need to integrate.

Thanks,
Partha

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem solved.

Issue is with the color format.

ImageDataGenerator outputs in RGB format whereas opencv imread reads it in BGR format.

So a BGR2RGB conversion is used to solve the issue.

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Also the default image resizer in ImageDataGenerator is "Nearest", i have used the same in opencv resize as well.